# Anagram word search

Tags: anagram, word-search

[image: anagrams]

Rules:

1. Words are scrambled - i.e. anagrams.
2. Valid paths - horizontally, vertically, diagonally.
3. No words are with less than 5 letters.
4. All words fall (more or less) within the same category - there are/could be other words as well, but they do not fall under the scope of this question.
5. If a word is derived by another word and you can find both words - only the longest word counts. For example, if you find success and successful, only successful counts as a find.
6. There are three 10-letter words and two 9-letter words on the grid.
7. Only two words are formed diagonally.
8. The words in total are 21.

Comment: This seems nearly impossible. Anagrams make it *way* too hard to actually find out what's intentionally in the grid and what's not. Solving this puzzle by hand is most likely going to take *several hours* of finding valid and invalid words, since there are so many options.

Comment: Well, that is why I introduced the rules - to make it easier to deduce what is a valid word and what is not.

Comment: The only "rules" that narrow it down are 3 and 4. 3 doesn't do much (especially since anagrams have so many options), and 4 isn't helpful unless you already have a list of words.

Comment: Maybe you can add a new rule or a riddle or a tag that could orientate players towards the path?

Comment: The issue is that 5-letter anagrams have 120 different permutations. 6-letter anagrams have even more. You've increased how much we have to check by over two orders of magnitude with the anagram rule, and that's assuming all the words are small. And it's hard to do each individual check, too!

Comment: I have added two more rules that could help. Especially in finding the category.

Comment: @Deusovi, Will's answer looks like evidence that this isn't "nearly impossible" -- though it's certainly way tougher than a normal wordsearch.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Indeed! Starting was tough, as I had words like "knell," "betrothing," and "preen" which are hardly related at all; though once I spotted a few obviously related words, a lot started to come from that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The category connecting the words is

> Intellect / skill (though the last few don't seem to fit so nicely)

and they are

> CLEVER, BRIGHT, PERCEPTION, BRILLIANCE, EXPERT, WITTY, BRAINY, INTEL, KNOWLEDGE, SMART (thanks [Acerfire37](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28947/acerfire37)!), ABILITY, TALENT (forgive me lol), GENIUS, SHARP (black for clarity; thanks [Lashit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17070/lashit-jain)!), EXCELLENCE, CAPABLE, ADEPT (more forgiveness, please), ACUMEN, APTNESS, BRAVE, PERTINENCE

as shown below:

> [image]

Comment: So far you are right. :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva Is one of the E's in the second row supposed to be an I?

Comment: the row is actually shorter with  one letter than the word you are trying to make. It wouldn't fit on the row.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Ha, didn't even notice. So, then, is that not counting towards one of the 21 i imagine?

Comment: The 12-letter word? No. :)

Comment: I'm bad at this. >__>

Comment: I found Intuition too, but... there are only 2 I's on the word soup?

Comment: I found "smart".  The related words help a lot. I just searched up synonyms for the words you found already

Comment: "sharp" is present in the same column as "smart". Shift the whole rectangle (of "smart") up by 2 units.

Comment: There is one more 10-letter word waiting to be found.

Comment: There's PERTINENCE at the top but it's doubtful how well it fits the category.

Comment: This is the word... @GarethMcCaughan

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes, I've found that, LOOKING, and BRAVE, but the connection on those is iffy.

Comment: Brave is also one of the words. @Will

Comment: The last two words are 6 and 7 letters.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Got 'em! Edit coming.

Comment: Oh, is "intel" actually one of the words? I was disregarding it. Oh well.

Answer (score 5):

It appears the category is:

> words to do with general intelligence.

So far, I've found 20 I'm confident in, + 3 more possibilities:

> Excellence, Smart, Genius, Clever,
>  Bright, Perception, Pertinence, Knowledge, Witty,
>  Ability, Brilliance, Brainy (*corrected*), Adept, Acumen,
>  Brave, Aptness,
>  *Sharp*, Talent*, Capable*, Expert*,*
>  
>  **Others/Unsure:**
>  <strike>Rulers</strike>, Groove, Electing, Lenient
>  
> -------
>  *Sharp* from @LashitJain's comments
>  *Talent, Capable, Expert* from @Will's answer

Image:

> [image]

Comment: Rulers is not intended. Brain is a bit longer.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Figured. How about groove?